# Inner automorphisms of a $II_1$ factor

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am trying to show that any group action on a type $II_1$ factor $M$ which is in standard form (i.e. acting by left multiplication on $L^2(M)$), is spatially implemented. I'm not really sure how to show this. I tried to extend the action to one on all of $B(L^2(M))$ use the fact that it is inner there and then by density of $M\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is the cyclic vector) show that this unitary U is actually in M.

I can't get this to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you mean by an action being inner? Usually automorphisms are inner. And, why would it depend on the representation?

Comment: I think he means spatially implemented

Comment: I posted a solution explaining how to construct the unitary $U$ to spatially implement the action, but reading again the question it is not clear if that is what is being asked. There are factors with non-inner automorphisms (for instance full factors)

Comment: Yes Adrian, I was meant to ask if the action was spatially implemented.

Comment: Check out the unitary implementation of the automorphism group on page 115 [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIun-v13.pdf).  These unitaries don't necessarily belong to $M$ (see Adrián's comment: not all automorphisms are inner), but Ad $u_g$ is the spatial implementation you're looking for, I think.